# Regex works in Rubular but not in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix

Given a string like:

```
one/two one/three two/four five/six seven
```

I use this regex:

`(?<=\s)([^\/]*)(?=\/|\s)(?!.*\1\b)`

to get:

```
one
two
five
seven
```

This is the result that I want. All the unique "root" strings. It works in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), but bash does not return any matches.

I know that the regex I'm using contains an exclamation point which will confuse bash, but adding a slash escape character in front of it does not help, nor do single quotes around it.

I am using it in bash like this:

```
[[ $string =~ (?<=\s)([^\/]*)(?=\/|\s)(?!.*\1\b) ]] echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
```

I cannot use double quotes for the regex because the version of bash that I am using interprets things in double quotes as literal strings.

How can I make bash understand this regex?

Comment: Fairly sure bash doesn't understand lookarounds.

Comment: [Maybe something like this?](http://ideone.com/5JYrdO)

Comment: Hmm, yeah that will probably work for my purposes. Thanks a bunch! I wonder then if it is possible to match what I want with a regex in bash without using lookarounds...

Comment: True. I suppose the Rubular check was not altogether valid. I was hoping that there would be some way to create a similar regex for bash though. According to @FrankieTheKneeMan, though, it may not be possible, or at least not with lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash definitely does not understand perl-compatible regular expressions. I'd stick to bash idioms:

```
string="one/two one/three two/four five/six seven"
roots=$(sed 's/\/[^[:blank:]]*//g' <<< "$string" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u)
echo "$roots"
```

or

```
roots=()                        # empty array
for word in $string             # no quotes to obtain word splitting
do
    roots+=( ${word%/*} )       # add to the array the bit before the last slash
done
printf "%s\n" "${roots[@]}" | sort -u
```

or, with bash 4, use an associative array to mimic the behaviour of a set.

```
declare -A roots                # an associative array
for word in $string             # no quotes to obtain word splitting
do
    roots[${word%/*}]=1
done
printf "%s\n" "${!roots[@]}"    # print out the hash keys
```